# How to localize an international address especially thoroughfare and subthoroughfare

Tags: ios, swift, localization, clplacemark, cnpostaladdress

I'm working on an app that heavily uses addresses in different countries. We have a bunch of ways we input them from getting addresses imported, to dropping pins on map, to reverse geocode our current location.

My current project is to correctly format international address:

In the USA:

`18 Street Name`

In Norway:

`Street Name 18`

I've figured out a bunch of ways to instantiate `CNMutablePostalAddress` with `CLPlacemark` to get some pretty good results, the problem I'm having is this.

I want just the street name and number returned as a one line string:
So:

`street1: placemarker.thoroughfare, (street name)
street2: placemarker.subThoroughfare (street number),`

but CNPostalAddress only has one `street` property, so to use it you need to do something like this:

`cNPostalAddress.street = placemarker.subThoroughfare + " " + placemarker.thoroughfare`

This will not work for countries like Norway where they are revered.

You can hack it and use the take the first line from the formatted address:

`CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: placemarker.mailingAddress , style: .mailingAddress)`

but that's super hacky and I'm sure it will break with countries that order their mailing address differently like japan.

At the moment I can't even find any resources that tell me which countries reverse `subThoroughfare` and `thoroughfare`, because if I had a list like that I could just reverse it manually.

Here is some sample code of what I've managed so far:

```
static func mulitLineAddress(from placemarker: CLPlacemark, detail: AddressDetail) -> String {
    let address = MailingAddress(
        street1: placemarker.thoroughfare,
        street2: placemarker.subThoroughfare,
        city: placemarker.locality,
        state: placemarker.administrativeArea,
        postalCode: placemarker.postalCode,
        countryCode: placemarker.country)

    return self.mulitLineAddress(from: address, detail: detail)
}


static func mulitLineAddress(from mailingAddress: MailingAddress, detail: AddressDetail) -> String {

let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()

let street1 = mailingAddress.street1 ?? ""
let street2 = mailingAddress.street2 ?? ""
let streetSpacing = street1.isEmpty && street2.isEmpty ? "" : " "
let streetFull = street1 + streetSpacing + street2

switch detail {
case .street1:
    address.street = street1
case .street2:
    address.street = street2
case .streetFull:
    address.street = streetFull
case .full:
    address.country = mailingAddress.countryCode ?? ""
    fallthrough
case .withoutCountry:
    address.street = streetFull
    address.city = mailingAddress.city ?? ""
    address.state = mailingAddress.state ?? ""
    address.postalCode = mailingAddress.postalCode ?? ""
}

return CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: address, style: .mailingAddress)
}
```

Any ideas? Even resources like list of countries that reverse `street1` and `street2` would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up taking a hybrid approach.

For the `CLPlacemark` to the `CNMutablePostalAddress()` it's pretty stright forward:

`cnPostalAddress.street = placemarker.postalAddress?.street`

However this doesn't work any any other input method and can't be modified to a different format from the `CNMutablePostalAddress()`

When bringing in address info from other sources I needed to do it manually, here is a bit of an example that works with a few countries:

```
static private func generateLocalizedStreetAddress(from adderss: MailingAddress) -> String {
    guard adderss.localizedStreet.isEmpty else { return adderss.localizedStreet ?? "" }

    let country = CountryCode.country(for: adderss.countryCode)
    let thoroughfare = adderss.thoroughfare ?? ""
    let subThoroughfare = adderss.subThoroughfare ?? ""
    let delimiter = self.generateDelimiter(from: thoroughfare, and: subThoroughfare, with: country)

    switch country {
    case .belgium, .czechRepublic, .denmark, .finland, .germany, .latvia, .netherlands, .norway, .poland, .portugal, .sweden:
        return thoroughfare + delimiter + subThoroughfare
    default:
        return subThoroughfare + delimiter + thoroughfare
    }
}

static private func generateDelimiter(from thoroughfare: String, and subThoroughfare: String, with country: Country) -> String {
    guard !thoroughfare.isEmpty && !subThoroughfare.isEmpty else { return "" }

    switch country {
    case .spain:
        return ", "
    default:
        return " "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CNPostalAddressFormatter` has an interesting API to get an `NSAttributedString` where each address component is identified in it. You could use this to pull out just the information you want, like the street which includes the properly localized sub-thoroughfare and thoroughfare no matter where it may exist in the postal address.

```
let addressFormatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
let attributedAddress = addressFormatter.attributedString(from: postalAddress, withDefaultAttributes: [:])
let nsString = attributedAddress.string as NSString
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length)

var street: String?

attributedAddress.enumerateAttributes(in: range, options: []) { result, range, stop in
    if let component = result[NSAttributedString.Key(CNPostalAddressPropertyAttribute)] as? String {
        if component == CNPostalAddressStreetKey {
            street = nsString.substring(with: range)
            stop.pointee = true
        }
    }
}
```

I've also filed feedback with Apple to add a more powerful and flexible API: FB8648023 Template API desired to format addresses with specified components similar to `DateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`